# How to insert in seeds.ex data for Ecto timestamp inserted_at

Tags: elixir, ecto

I'm trying to hardcode some test/initial values into `seeds.ex` for the Ecto timestamp `inserted_at` but I'm getting errors:

```
MyProj.Repo.insert!(%MyProj.MyModel{inserted_at[:month]: 5, name: "nananana", email: "blablabla@gmail.com", tel: "99999999"})
```

I've already tried using `.` instead of brackets but it's the same.

Comment: What did you expect `inserted_at[:month]: 5` to do here? You probably want `inserted_at: datetime` where `datetime` is a `NaiveDateTime` value.

Comment: Yes, but as per documentation if I can access it using dot notation should I also be able to insert using dot notation? Must I insert it using only the full naive = ~N[2000-01-01 23:00:07]

Comment: Ok, after reading it better documentation explicitly says we need to use `new/7` or the `~N` sigil to create one...

Comment: I tried: `inserted_at: ~N[2017-4-13 00:30:10]` but now I'm getting an error after migrating saying: `cannot parse "2017-4-13 00:30:10" as naive datetime, reason: :invalid_format`

Comment: Try `04` as the month instead of just `4`.

Comment: Error saying: `value ~N[2017-04-13 00:30:10]` for `MyProj.MyModel.inserted_at` in `insert` does not match type Ecto.DateTime`

Comment: `inserted_at: Ecto.DateTime.from_erl(NaiveDateTime.to_erl(~N[2017-04-13 00:30:10]))` :: ([`Ecto.DateTime.from_erl`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.DateTime.html#from_erl/1))

Comment: @mudasobwa. It works. Could you turn this into an answer so that I can accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Ecto` expects an [`Ecto.DateTime`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.DateTime.html) struct there.

There are many possibilities to produce this struct out of what you have. As you have a `NaiveDateTime`, this should work:

```
inserted_at: ~N[2017-04-13 00:30:10]
             |> NaiveDateTime.to_erl()
             |> Ecto.DateTime.from_erl()
```

Whether you had an erlang date, it could be even simpler:

```
inserted_at: Ecto.DateTime.from_erl({{2017, 4, 13}, {0, 30, 10}})
```